# C# send e-mail error. How to send an e-mail with this way?

Tags: c#, email

This code is not running. I want to send a mail, but ı can't.

I want to send an e-mail, when ı run the code. But it's not working. I realy neeed help.

```
public static void SendNotification(string filepath)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient mailServer = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["host"], int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portnumber"]));
            mailServer.EnableSsl = true;
             System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender_username"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sender_password"]);

            string to = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RECEIVE"];
            string cc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CC"];
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(from, to);
            msg.Subject = "";
            msg.Body = "Test Mail.";
            mailServer.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is it failing?

Comment: What makes you think this code isn't working?

Comment: miracdogan's answer is working. I have missing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missing things.

Here is

```
private static void SendMail(string subject, string content)
{
    try

    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("YOURMAİL");
        mail.To.Add("MAİLTO");
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = content;
        SmtpServer.Port = 25;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("YOURMAİL", "YOURMAİLPASSWORD");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

This is simplest way to send mail. Don't forget to add using System.Net.Mail;
You need to add `mail.From`. It's very important.